# EF6 - Truncate string fields to avoid DB conflicts before SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use a Windows Service to save records in db regularly with Entity Framework 6 Code First.
Some of my clients may send bad data according to DB constraints (string length violation). My clients don't have HMI.

I'm looking for a way to truncate these string violations before SaveChanges() and log them.

My first idea was to loop on all validation errors and compare string length to StringLengthAttribute in db configuration:

```
foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationErrors in db.GetValidationErrors())
{
   foreach (DbValidationError validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
   {
      //Test if EF6 value is longer than DB max size
      //If greater, truncate it and log a warning message
   }
}
```

My other (bad) solution was to to truncate string fields in Data layer but it's not efficient at all. Here is an poor example for only one property...

```
private string pcName;
[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string PCName
{
   get { return pcName; }
   set
   {
       const int stringLengthAttribute = 100; // Should be equal to StringLengthAttribute
       if (value.Length <= stringLengthAttribute)
          pcName = value;
       else
          {
             pcName = value.Substring(0, stringLengthAttribute);
             Log.Warn("PC.pcName truncated from " + value + " to " + pcName);
          }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `it's not efficient at all`? Why would this be less efficient than sending bad data and doing the fixing later? The measurement is probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not efficient because lot of work on my side and I loose code flexibility if some changes happen on DB string sizes. :) In fact, there's a way to check validation constraints before saving them. So that's why it might be a good idea to investiguate more options.

Comment: I never found validation attributes on EF entities useful. Validation should normally happen elsewhere architecturally. Often, validation is context dependent and the action taken on validation failure also varies. For example, it seems better to refuse bad input instead of silently deleting some data. These attributes also are not versatile enough to cover all cases. So I always found it best to abandon them.

Comment: Similar question for an earlier EF version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081109/entity-framework-4-0-automatically-truncate-trim-string-before-insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution usually is to fix data as it enters the system. Don't even send bad/unvalidated data to the database. This is pointless because you have the same validation/fixing code but in a worse place.

In the place where you wrote

```
  //Test if EF6 value is longer than DB max size
  //If greater, truncate it and log a warning message
```

you will need the same code that you currently designated as "bad".

Also, don't make the setter modify the data that is being set. Setters should not contain such logic and the getter should return the same data that was set.

Instead, only set correct values. E.g. `myEntity.MyString = userInput.Truncate(200);`.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Any solution to take care of StringLengthAttribute automatically?

Comment: It's really bad to make the setter take such an action. It breaks the common assumption that `prop = val; Assert(prop == val);`. If you want to go ahead with that you could modify the T4 template that generates the entities to make use of those attributes. Or, use reflection at runtime.

Comment: Now I don't understand it :)

Comment: Ok for settler warning. I've to check how my clients can validate string sizes according to db constraints. Strings are defined locally (means in client) and DB constraints are defined in server...

Comment: If the DB size can be different attributes won't help. You can query the database schema at runtime to find the maximum supported length.

Comment: Ok, so hard work these days. :) Thanks for your clarification!