# C# - Can BulkInsert() automatically truncate strings that are too long?

Tags: c#, bulkinsert, dbcontext, truncate, bulkupdate

I am using a lot of bulk insert calls similar to this:

```
List<Object> list = someSetOfData;
dbcontext.BulkInsert(list);
```

Each object has multiple string properties that can only be a certain length in the database. Based on the amount of data that is getting inserted, it would slow down the application if I manually check that each string is the correct length before I insert it. Is there a way that I can tell BulkInsert to automatically truncate any strings that are too long (so that it won't throw exceptions)? Also if there is a way to do that, will it tell me when it actually truncates a string?

And if not, what else would you recommend trying?

Comment: It seems like you should enforce things like property lengths in your model - not in the method you use to insert the data.  You can decorate model properties with StringLength attributes so the model matches the database.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed interesting, you would have to call something else before hitting savechanges.

[Entity Framework 4.0 Automatically Truncate/Trim String Before Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081109/entity-framework-4-0-automatically-truncate-trim-string-before-insert)

Another solution for .NET Core:
https://medium.com/@paullorica/automatically-truncate-strings-in-an-ef-core-entity-based-on-maxlength-property-93e17ea7cd43